# Is there a way to get a companies name from their office networks ip address

Tags: ip-address

Is there a way to get a companies name from their offices ip address ? (Note this is their office ip address as in the ip address that a employee at their office would connect to the internet with, not their websites ip address)

There are some services like leadfeeder that scan your google analytics (i guess for a list of ips) and then match them to company names to let you know who has visited, but is there a way to be able to check this sort of data manually ?

Comment: Check the WHOIS record for their IP address. Usually, that will be their ISP's information, but some companies have IP blocks registered in their own. Also try reverse and forward DNS, though that's less reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is.

Some analytic services offer just this - such as Lucky Orange.

If you're looking to attempt it yourself there are a number of [IP Geolocation databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514749/best-ip-to-country-database) you can choose from. Some are 'open' and others require you to pay for access. None are 100% reliable however and you'll want to keep that in mind when using this data!

Be wary of any company that is offering to expose IPs via Google Analytics as this is against their Terms of Service. Attempting to identify client IDs and being caught will have you blacklisted from their service.

Answer (score 1):

Also, there is a service called nslookup that does reverse ip to domain name search. If given an ip it will try to find the relevant hostname(s) associated with it. Work from there then. If on *nix, try "man nslookup" and e.g. "man host". Online, try http://network-tools.com/nslook/ .

Sometimes no hostnames are associated with a given ip but the ip will be part of an ip range that was assigned to an organization/company/... Query the RIPE Database in that case, cf. https://www.ripe.net/manage-ips-and-asns/db/faq/faq-db